# How to put together the custom adapter, date models and Layouts for the TableView library by evrencoskun to work?

Tags: android, tableview

I just recently started programming on android and my basic ListViews no longer work for the data I need to show so I'm trying to use the TableView library by evrencoskun (https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView#documentation).
The problem is I'm not quite following the documentation of how to implement it.

The documentation shows how to create a "custom adapter", "date models" and "Layouts" but I don't know if creating all of those is mandatory for my TableView to work (also I don't get where should I put the "date models") and I have no idea of how to link them up for my ListView to work.

I was also considering using ISchwarz23 ListView library which is supposed to have all the same features but payment for a license is needed so that's a big no no no.

Comment: As a note ISchwarz23 ListView does not seem to offer Fixed Row Headers, two way scrolling, auto sizing of Column widths based on data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just improved the documentation for TableView, so I might be able to help.

Custom Adapter is Mandatory. (Much like it is on a more complicated Listview)

Data Models, this is sort of Mandatory BUT depending on your data and as long as you don't want to filter or sort your data then there is a shortcut to not use these. (I have an example that does not use data models as it displays just text Strings)
e.g. In the below Listview Adapter Creation (the Bold highlighted String Object is your single Data Model Type)
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<**String**>(this, 
         R.layout.activity_listview, dataArray);

Layouts at least one is Mandatory for a very basic layout but 3/4 layouts are required to have a reasonable looking table (Row Header, Column Header, Cells and optionally Corner)

Your data models are just POJO classes, so you can place them anywhere you want in your projects java source directories. But for better structure you might want to place them in there own sub package.

As for

> I have no idea of how to link them up for my ListView to work.

This does not link to a Listview widget, it could replace a ListView widget but more commonly replaces GridLayout, TableLayout or the Grid Layout Managers of a RecyclerView widget.

The two sample Apps give you a good basis for your code.

I would get familiar with RecyclerViews first as a step up from ListViews (as this is really just a complicated RecyclerView)

If you are still struggling then ask another question with details of what data you have and how you want it laid out in the table cells.